# How to check if unused Recoil atom consumes memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, recoiljs

I want to check if unused Recoil atom consumes memory.

Since recoil value is maintained until we exit the app, it would mean that the value is stored somewhere.
It's just my assumption so I would like to prove it.

I tried to use Memory tab in Chrome Developer Tool but there were too many objects to check so it was impossible to find Recoil atoms. How can I do this? I'm using Next JS.